# GWT drag and drop animation

Tags: gwt, animation, drag-and-drop

I have a flow panel with many photo-widgets inside (gallery with random number of rows and columns, depends on screen size) for which I want to implement drag and drop behavior to change their order. I am using **gwt-dnd** library. Its `FlowPanelDropController` allows you to define your own positioner (delimiter) which shows the candidate location for dropping the dragged widget.

I want this positioner to be the empty space with defined width, and the challenging thing is to implement sliding animation effect for the when positioner is added and removed. 
If you are a desktop Picasa app user you know what I mean: the target row slides both sides (little to the left, little to the right) extending the space between the items where you are going to drop a photo.

The whole thing is complex enough, but any help related to how to apply the animation for positioner attach/detach is appreciated. Maybe I need to use a different approach (e.g., use GWT native dnd instead of gwt-dnd lib and no "positioners" at all) if you have any ideas how this could be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: You might have try something in jquery and then port it using GwtQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I ended up overriding `AbstractPositioningDropController` (parent of `FlowPanelDropController`) and adding some extra features.

1) `newPositioner()` method now builds the Label, which is vertical space with some small width, height and decoration. This widget's element has constant `id` (say, "POSITIONER"), which helps to distinguish between multiple positioners if you plan to have several of them while navigating with a drag object over multiple drop targets. Also some `transition` CSS effects were applied to the Label, which will be responsible for handling animated extension of Label's width.

2) in `onEnter()` I do the following

```
        ...
        removePositioner(getPositionerElement());

        Widget positioner = newPositioner();
        dropTarget.insert(positioner, targetIndex);
        animatePositionerExtension();
```

where `getPositionerElement()` returns `DOM.getElementById(POSITIONER)`

At the same time `removePositioner(..)` resets the id of this element to something abstract and ideally should provide some animation before calling `.removeFromParent()`. But I didn't have enough time to properly debug this so ended up just removing the old positioner with no animation.

Method `animatePositionerExtension()` contains the code that changes the width of the positioner widget, so that CSS `transition` will catch that and provides animation.

All access to positioner widget in the class should be provided through updated methods.

3) `onLeave()` contains line `removePositioner(getPositionerElement());`

4) In the end of `onMove()` I added a couple of lines:

```
     galleryWidget.extendHoveredRow(targetIndex - 1);
     animatePositionerExtension();
```

where `extendHoveredRow(hoveredWidgetOrdinal)` implemented the logic to "limit" the sliding effect in the single line:

```
int rowHovered = -1;
public void extendHoveredRow(int hoveredWidgetOrdinal) {
    int newRowHovered = getRowByOrdinalHovered(hoveredWidgetOrdinal);
    if (rowHovered != newRowHovered) {
        // adjust position of items in the previously hovered row
        int firstInPreviouslyHoveredRow = (rowHovered - 1) * itemsInARow;
        shiftFirstItemLeft(firstInPreviouslyHoveredRow, false);

        rowHovered = newRowHovered;
        // extend this row
        int firstInThisRow = getOrdinalFirstInThisRowByOrdinal(hoveredWidgetOrdinal);
        shiftFirstItemLeft(firstInThisRow, true);
    }
}
```

This is in short how I did the thing. And still there's some room for improvements, like adding animated removal.

Again, it's all about overriding DropController and manipulations with elements inside the "gallery" widget. The benefit of this approach is that I remain in the gwt-dnd operations framework, and also reused a bunch of existent code.

Some notes:

- CSS `transition` is not supported in IE pre-9, but this is unrelated to
  this topic.
- Put a transparent "glass" div on top of the Image widget if you use it
  as a face of dragProxy. This will save you tons of time trying to
  understand why either setting element's `draggable` to false, or
  calling `event.preventDefault()` somewhere else, or other workarounds don't work in one or several browsers and the image itself is being dragged instead of the whole dragProxy widget.